# Typescript unexpected token <

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, jsx, tsx

I'm use mocha for testing tsx component from command line.
I use for compilation ts-node package. But it can't complile jsx. My tsconfig.json have jsx compile option.

> mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register,js:babel-core/register ./src/testing.tsx

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "es6",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "babel_cache",
    "build",
    "docs",
    "gradle",
    "node_modules",
    "out",
    "test",
    "tools",
    "typings"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

/src/testing.tsx :

```
import * as React from 'react';
class Foo extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render () {
        return <span>yep</span>;
    }
}
<Foo />
```

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262334/tsx-webpack-compile-fails-unexpected-token?rq=1