# Why is TypeScript not parsing my `react-native-web` code? (NOT using `create-react-native-app`)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native-web

```
Already tried https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/832
```

Got:

[image: error message]

for:

[image: code]

I thought the issue might be the linter error I was getting b/c of the `react-native` aliasing of `react-native-web` (which for some reason, TypeScript can't figure out...). Was able to resolve that via `npm i -D react-native @types/react-native`.

However, still got the same error.

Next, I tried converting my SFC (stateless functional component) to a class component. Still got:

[image: similar error message]

So I'm wondering why I'm getting this error message even though [I've configured TypeScript](https://github.com/English3000/Elixir/commit/1bd5f96384805d8087c4051780c204d8ce112ef2).

Answer (score 0):

*[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262334/tsx-webpack-compile-fails-unexpected-token/55231802#55231802) was my issue:* In my `tsconfig.json`, I had `"jsx": "preserve"`. Switching to `"jsx": "react"` fixed it!