# TypeScript not parsing react-native-web code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-web

> Already tried suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231350/why-is-typescript-not-parsing-my-react-native-web-code-not-using-create-rea) and [here](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/832) with no luck

I have a project with a directory structure like this:

```
.
  - /app
  - /web
```

`app` is a react native app (created manually, not with `create-react-native-app`).

`web` is a react app created using `create-react-app`.

Both use TypeScript.

I'm trying to render a component from `app` in the `web` application using `react-native-web`, but TypeScript doesn't seem to be parsing the file as I get this error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
> export type Props = {
```

Given that TypeScript is working fine within `app` and `web` independently, I'm not sure what I'm missing. One slight quirk of the project is that, because `create-react-app` doesn't allow relative imports from outside its own `src` folder, I've had to symlink `app` using `npm link app` in the `web` directory in order to import the app components.

Not sure if that's causing the problem, but I'm pretty stumped so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For sanity's sake, have you tried copying in app directly instead of symlinking and seeing if that works?  I have had issues with react scripts and other utilities not handling links the way you think they would.

Comment: @zero298 you mean copying it into `node_modules`? Just gave that a try but no luck :( good thought though - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution ended up being to add `ts-loader` to the webpack config of my React for web app. This was made slightly harder by the fact that `create-react-app` doesn't allow modifying its config files, but I was able to do so using [react app rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)

I also had to change TypeScript's `noEmit` to `false` to ensure tsc is used for compilation as well as type checking (had to do this in react-app-rewired too, because CRA overwrites that setting in `tsconfig.json` if you try to change it).

Still slightly confusing to me why this was needed, given TypeScript was being parsed perfectly fine in the web and mobile apps individually.